# Giving information to a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I got a (maybe a bit silly) question.
I'm making a photo gallery using javascript. I need to give every image some information (a *id*), so i can ask javascript what image is currently open.

**Example:**

I got a array of some images. Those images have a *id* 1, 2 and 3. When I'm using the gallery to slide through the images, I want to know what image Im looking at.

It can be done by giving the images *alt* the information I need. So I can go like;

```
var id = document.getElementById("image").alt;
```

But I though this wasn't the way to do it. Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Comment: You can use any of data attributes. You can set a data-title attribute, or even just use title.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you're proceeding. In your code you are using "image" as an ID, then you read an "id" from an "ALT" attribute. I'm pretty sure this is indeed *not* the way to do it. To know "what image you're looking at", you need to ask yourself - what must one do to *look at an image*? If he e.g. **clicks** on it, you just add a click handler and set an attribute there: $(this).attr("clicked") (*and clear any leftover attribute from other images*). Without actually seeing the gallery code, one can't be much more specific than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have multiple `<img>` elements. You could give each of them the same `class` value so you can easily get a reference to all of them. You could then use `data-` attributes for any data you want to assign to them.

```
<img class="gallery-image" data-id="1" ...
<img class="gallery-image" data-id="2" ...
<img class="gallery-image" data-id="3" ...
```

JavaScript

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-image');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var id = images[i].getAttribute('data-id');

    ...
}
```

Comment: From The [W3 HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes), you can access a data-* attribute by using `images[i].dataset.attribute;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove a custom attribute using jquery to your image to indicate it's active:

```
$(..).attr('c-active', true);
```

will result:

```
<img src=".." c-active/>
```

Setting it to false will remove that attribute.

Since the attribute isn't a standard html syntax, some framework / browser might not be happy about it.

You can also use jquery data:

```
$(..).data('c-active',true);
$(..).data('c-active',false);
```

Or just keep a simple javascript variable to indicate which image id is active (but you will have to update this everytime the image slides)

```
var activeId = 5;
```